# How do I move games into the main app list?

Tags: games, organization

I often forget about the games I have because I have to open the Xbox Live Games app to see the list of games.

I'd rather see games as part of the list of all apps that appears when you swipe left from the home screen. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have often wanted to do the same, but we cant. :( once the developer sets the application as a "game" it will install under the Games hub, and lives there.

Comment: care to explain the downvote? The information I posted is accurate. You can't move an item from the games list to the main app list.

Answer (score 4):

Games can be pinned to the start screen - simply go to the Xbox Live games app, swipe to the collection tab (if required), and press and hold your favourite game, until the context menu appears -- the first option allows you to "pin to start" - you can also choose to add a review to show in the marketplace or uninstall if you wanted.